# how can I get expr:content value from Blogger using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blogger

how can I get `expr:content` value from Blogger using JavaScript?

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId'/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postId'/>
```

I tried `getElementsByTagName("meta")`

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

As well as `querySelectorAll()`

```
var metas = document.querySelectorAll("meta[expr\\:content]");
for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("expr:content"))}
txt=x.expr:content;
```

But I didn't receive any result, I want to have two variable which receives results

```
x=number of blogId
y=number of postId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var blogId = document.querySelector("meta[itemprop='blogId']").getAttribute('expr:content'),
    postId = document.querySelector("meta[itemprop='postId']").getAttribute('expr:content');
console.log(postId);
console.log(blogId);
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/nuxohofoso/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta"),
    metaData = {}, i, item;
for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    item = metas[i].getAttribute("itemprop");
    if (item == "blogId" || item == "postId"){
        metaData[item] = metas[i].getAttribute("expr:content");
    }
}
    console.log(metaData); // this should give you an object with needed data
```

Comment: he give me as a result **[Object object]**

Comment: I've just checked my code with your html markup(meta tags) and it gives me `Object {blogId: "data:blog.blogId", postId: "data:post.id"}`. Are you sure that you haven't missed something?

Comment: OP must have replaced `console.log` with `alert`. LOL

Comment: @AdamAzad, Sure looks that way.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following script right after <b:includable id='post' var='post'>

```
<script>
    var myBlogId = &#39;<data:blog.blogId/>&#39;
    var myPostId = &#39;<data:post.id/>&#39;
</script>
```